# Can't get PHPMailer to work

Tags: php, phpmailer

So I am trying to get PHPMailer to work, I have downloaded the latest release and configured it according to the documentation, I have tried telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 to check that I can get trough and that works, i have tried ping smtp.gmail.com and that works, I have disabled two-step-authentication from Google and I have gone trough the captcha-validation. I have also turned on access for apps in my google security settings. I have tried with ssl and with tls, but whatever I try, I still get

```
SMTP connect() failed. bool(false)
```

This is my setup at the moment

```
<?php  

require("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php"); // path to the PHPMailer class

$mail = new PHPmailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'mymail@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';


$mail->From = 'sndrem@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Sindre Moldeklev';
$mail->addReplyTo('mymail@gmail.com', 'Reply adress');
$mail->addAddress('somemail@live.no', 'Full Name');

$mail->Subject = 'Here is an email';
$mail->Body = 'This is the body of the email';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the alternative body';

echo (extension_loaded('openssl')?'SSL loaded':'SSL not loaded')."\n"; 

var_dump($mail->send());

?>
```

I even added the

```
echo (extension_loaded('openssl')?'SSL loaded':'SSL not loaded')."\n";
```

To check if openssl is loaded, and it returns SSL loaded, so that is ok.

It drives me crazy not getting this to work. I am trying to run it trough xaamp on an iMac 27" osx Yosemite v. 10.10.1 . I have also uncommented the extension=openssl_dll from php.ini.

I feel like I have tried everything, but maybe someone here has some extra tips that I still have not tried?

I am grateful for any answers that can lead me closer to a solution.

For info, this is the latest message between the script and the server.

```
SSL loaded 2015-01-08 17:25:59  Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, t=300, opt=array ( ) 2015-01-08 17:25:59 Connection: opened 2015-01-08 17:25:59  SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 2015-01-08 17:25:59   SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 mx.google.com ESMTP ql3sm1265527lbb.48 - gsmtp " 2015-01-08 17:25:59  SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 mx.google.com ESMTP ql3sm1265527lbb.48 - gsmtp " 2015-01-08 17:25:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP ql3sm1265527lbb.48 - gsmtp 2015-01-08 17:25:59    CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2015-01-08 17:25:59    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 2015-01-08 17:25:59   SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] " 2015-01-08 17:25:59   SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] " 2015-01-08 17:25:59  SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] " 2015-01-08 17:25:59 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 35882577 " 2015-01-08 17:25:59   SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] 250-SIZE 35882577 " 2015-01-08 17:25:59    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] 250-SIZE 35882577 " 2015-01-08 17:25:59   SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME " 2015-01-08 17:25:59    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME " 2015-01-08 17:25:59   SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME " 2015-01-08 17:25:59  SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS " 2015-01-08 17:25:59    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS " 2015-01-08 17:25:59  SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS " 2015-01-08 17:25:59 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 2015-01-08 17:25:59 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 2015-01-08 17:25:59  SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 2015-01-08 17:25:59 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING " 2015-01-08 17:25:59  SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING " 2015-01-08 17:25:59   SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING " 2015-01-08 17:25:59  SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING " 2015-01-08 17:25:59    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING " 2015-01-08 17:25:59  SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING " 2015-01-08 17:25:59 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8 " 2015-01-08 17:25:59    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 " 2015-01-08 17:25:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [81.191.67.35] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 2015-01-08 17:25:59    CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2015-01-08 17:25:59  SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 2015-01-08 17:25:59   SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS " 2015-01-08 17:25:59    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS " 2015-01-08 17:25:59   SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Nettside-til-pappa/PHPMailer/class.smtp.php on line 338
2015-01-08 17:25:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2015-01-08 17:25:59  SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""      2015-01-08 17:25:59  SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "MIAf�5*:�u���\^� N�\��� 6��I���f�~���xA�ٿ��xb㕈��7�q�-���  �O���䳽�q]��g��J�n�t��5E�mq���cC�MH��UHTv��B������/Dj���#m+��^����}�ui�q-    �[�V#eP&�H�y>J>1'���D�/�l�37�4�G�PkU�f���&�4wlON��i��aX����-崟�{��w��Eu�P;�]ʪ���~6����.;v  " 2015-01-08 17:25:59 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "MIAf�5*:�u���\^� N�\��� 6��I���f�~���xA�ٿ��xb㕈��7�q�-��� �O���䳽�q]��g��J�n�t��5E�mq���cC�MH��UHTv��B������/Dj���#m+��^����}�ui�q-    �[�V#eP&�H�y>J>1'���D�/�l�37�4�G�PkU�f���&�4wlON��i��aX����-崟�{��w��Eu�P;�]ʪ���~6����.;v  " 2015-01-08 17:25:59 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "MIAf�5*:�u���\^� N�\��� 6��I���f�~���xA�ٿ��xb㕈��7�q�-���    �O���䳽�q]��g��J�n�t��5E�mq���cC�MH��UHTv��B������/Dj���#m+��^����}�ui�q-    �[�V#eP&�H�y>J>1'���D�/�l�37�4�G�PkU�f���&�4wlON��i��aX����-崟�{��w��Eu�P;�]ʪ���~6����.;v  " 2015-01-08 17:25:59 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "~���" ��r���$N��jd&�F�D|:�D�~��Fv�����X�܂�*19d�> " 2015-01-08 17:25:59    SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "MIAf�5*:�u���\^� N�\��� 6��I���f�~���xA�ٿ��xb㕈��7�q�-��� �O���䳽�q]��g��J�n�t��5E�mq���cC�MH��UHTv��B������/Dj���#m+��^����}�ui�q-    �[�V#eP&�H�y>J>1'���D�/�l�37�4�G�PkU�f���&�4wlON��i��aX����-崟�{��w��Eu�P;�]ʪ���~6����.;v  ~���" ��r���$N��jd&�F�D|:�D�~��Fv�����X�܂�*19d�> " 2015-01-08 17:25:59    SERVER -> CLIENT: MIAf�5*:�u���\^� N�\��� 6��I���f�~���xA�ٿ��xb㕈��7�q�-���  �O���䳽�q]��g��J�n�t��5E�mq���cC�MH��UHTv��B������/Dj���#m+��^����}�ui�q-    �[�V#eP&�H�y>J>1'���D�/�l�37�4�G�PkU�f���&�4wlON��i��aX����-崟�{��w��Eu�P;�]ʪ���~6����.;v  ~���" ��r���$N��jd&�F�D|:�D�~��Fv�����X�܂�*19d�>  2015-01-08 17:25:59 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: MIAf�5*:�u���\^� N�\��� 6��I���f�~���xA�ٿ��xb㕈��7�q�-���   �O���䳽�q]��g��J�n�t��5E�mq���cC�MH��UHTv��B������/Dj���#m+��^����}�ui�q-    �[�V#eP&�H�y>J>1'���D�/�l�37�4�G�PkU�f���&�4wlON��i��aX����-崟�{��w��Eu�P;�]ʪ���~6����.;v  ~���" ��r���$N��jd&�F�D|:�D�~��Fv�����X�܂�*19d�>  2015-01-08 17:25:59 Connection: closed 2015-01-08 17:25:59  SMTP connect() failed. bool(false)
```

Comment: Are you sure the port is 587?

Comment: Also, it seems that smtp.google.com is not a valid host name...

Comment: Did you Google for the error code ? This could help you : http://davidwalsh.name/php-ssl-curl-error

Comment: Where would I update the .pem-file @LorenzMeyer ?

Answer (score 0):

> try to change following things:

```
$mail->Port = 465;  //port number
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  //smtp secure
$mail->setFrom('sndrem@gmail.com', 'Sindre Moldeklev'); //set from accept two parameters
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  //smtp auth
```

Comment: I tried this, and the error message got a lot shorter, but I was still not able to connect..

Comment: This is the error message now: SSL loaded 2015-01-08 17:54:24 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, t=300, opt=array ( ) 2015-01-08 17:54:24 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2015-01-08 17:54:24 SMTP connect() failed. bool(false)

Comment: @SindreMoldeklev is fopenis ON?

Comment: Where do I check if it is @Priyank ?

Comment: @SindreMoldeklev search this "allow_url_fopen " in php.ini or put "php_value allow_url_fopen On" to your .htaccess file

Comment: @SindreMoldeklev did you allow fopen?

Comment: @SindreMoldeklev follow this document,may this solve your problem.https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried everything that page says. Still nothing.

Comment: Could it be that I am using Xaamp to test or should that not have anything to say on the output?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Host to **"localhost"**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I was just trying to help.  How was my post not trying to answer the question?

Comment: I didn't say you weren't trying to help, but the above is a comment, not really an answer.

Comment: Well that is subjective don't you think